# How to make my blog site visible in Google Search

Tags: google-search

I created a blog site a long time ago, but it is still not visible in Google Search.

Please can anyone guide me?

Comment: Is it self-hosted or are you using a service like Blogger or WordPress.com?

Comment: im using google component Blogger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign up for [Google's Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and describe your site therein.

Even better, have your blog auto-create a sitemap.xml and submit that to Google (using the aforementioned Webmaster tools). My blog gets indexed within hours if not minutes after each posting.

Comment: yap did the same above but its not getting indexed

Comment: Then perhaps you've run afoul of Google's rules for indexing sites.

Comment: please can you correct me, with any online guide

Comment: [How do I get my blog indexed by the search engines?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/blogger/thread?tid=14fa23d55246c1c4&hl=en) from Blogger Help.